# Nested value query inside rails where

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

to a query
`@products = @products.offset(offset).limit(@limit).where(status: "visible").where.not(inventory: [nil, {}])`

how can I add
`where.not((product.inventory.length == 1 and product.inventory.first[1]["quantity"].to_i == 0)))))`
?

i.e. how to check length of property `inventory` and if 1 check first entry's quantity, and satisfy the condition above?

Comment: What database do you use? Postgres? Is `inventory` a jsonb column?

Comment: postgres yes, and inventory is jsonb yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jsonb operators

```rb
@products = 
  @products
    .offset(offset)
    .limit(@limit)
    .where(status: "visible")
    .where.not(inventory: [nil, {}])
    .where.not("ARRAY(select (jsonb_each(inventory)).value->>'quantity' as integer)='{0}'")
```

Comment: PG::Error: ERROR: cannot get array length of a non-array : SELECT DISTINCT "products"."id", "products"."priority" AS alias_0, "products"."id" AS alias_1 FROM "products" INNER JOIN "categories" ON "categories"."id" = "products"."category_id" AND "categories"."deleted" = $1 LEFT OUTER JOIN "product_translations" ON "product_translations"."product_id" = "products"."id" WHERE "products"."deleted" = $2 AND (categories.company_id =1) AND "products"."status" IN (0, 2) AND "products"."category_id" IN (11, 10, 5, 4, 2, 1, 3) AND "products"."status" = $3 ...

Comment: I double checked and inventory is indeed jsonb as showing on pgAdmin

Comment: I think it's because it's a jsonb object not an array

Comment: Please show an example value of `inventory` column.

Comment: in schema    `t.jsonb    "inventory",          default: {}`

Comment: Now it works but i think that condition is not working properly, the following product is not filtered out of the returned products

Comment: 2.4.6 :047 > Product.find(14).inventory
  Product Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."deleted" = $1 AND "products"."id" = $2 LIMIT 1  [["deleted", "f"], ["id", 14]]
 => {"werwe"=>{"sku"=>"", "barcode"=>"", "quantity"=>"0"}}

Comment: Maybe on the first answer we can utilize jsonb_object_keys then count keys returned?

Comment: No, it's something else. I'll update my answer later

Comment: Fixed again, please check